# Regex to match a string at all punctuation followed by a space or the end

Tags: javascript, regex

I am building a Javascript script that splits a paragraph into sentences. I am using this code with a regex to do that right now:

```
paragraph.match( /[^\.!\?]+[\.!\?(?="|')]+(\s|$)/g );
```

This works great except for the fact that if there is a word with the punctuation in it in the sentence then it splits it there. So for example if I have a sentence like: `Why is about.me so popular?` I want it to say that that is one sentence and return an array like `['Why is about.me so popular?']`, but with this regex it splits it at the `.` in `about.me`. I know the issue is in this part of the regex `[^\.!\?]` because I am saying that it can't have end mark punctuation in the sentence. So what I really need is one that only allows characters that are not the punctuation followed by a space. The issue is I cannot figure out how to do that.

Any ideas? I tried `[^\.!\?(?=\s)]`, but that did not work. Any ideas?

Clarification:

I need to use `.match()` because I want to be able to retain the punctuation.

Comment: you cannot have a lookahead within a class

Comment: @WalterTross ok that's what I thought so any idea how to do the same thing, but with a different method?

Comment: I don't think you should assume `[Why is about.me so popular?]` to be a single sentence.

Comment: @Sebas um... why not?

Comment: Because it is a *character class* containing the characters "W", "h", "y", " ", "i", "s", "a", "b", "o", "u", "t", ".", "m", "e", "p", "l", "r", and "?". IOW, it is equivalent to `[Why isabout.meplr?]` or `[ .?Wabehilmoprstuy]` or `[ .?Wabehilmopr-uy]`.

Comment: I just really think that you can't guess what is a semantically correct sentence. I'm going to put it this way: why is "Why is about" not a correct sentence?

Comment: @Sebas because it doesn't have a correct end punctuation.

Comment: @christophe relating to the previous comments and the OP's question you will notice that the problem here is not the punctuation.

Comment: @Sebas on the contrary, this is the core issue: identifying if a dot is an end punctuation or not. In "about.me", the dot does not mark the end of a sentence because it is immediately followed by a letter.

Comment: @Christophe But then what if the paragraph does not respect this rule?  The problem would indeed be different if there's a garantee that some rules are respected. However, to me, it clearly seems that the input paragraph comes from a human being...

Comment: @Sebas if the typing is wrong then there's not much you can do! This is true for any string match, not just punctuation.

Comment: @Sebas One can reasonably assume that a quoted dot or a dot that is not followed by whitespace or the end of input does not delimit a sentence. This has been done before.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a "lazy plus" (+?):

```
paragraph.match(/([\S\s]+?)[.!?](\s|$)/g);
```

This way, the match will end as soon as it hits the end of a sentence.

[\S\s] stands for "any character".

Comment: It's more common to use `.` to mean "any character". Also, I don't get the `\.` in between the first and second parenthesis, this should be the punctuation. Other than that, I agree that lazy plus with "any character" is the way to go. So, I think the regex should look like this: `paragraph.match( /.+?[\.!\?(?="|')]+(\s|$)/g )`

Comment: @Bikonja `.` doesn't exactly mean "any character" http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html . `\.` is the punctuation at the end of the sentence.

Comment: You're right. I default in my head to setting the dot to match new line too which is not possible in javascript. Still, OP specified his punctuation to be ., ! or ? and not just a dot so am I missing something here?

Comment: [`[^]` will break e. g. in IE/JScript < 9 and Opera < 10.5](http://PointedEars.de/es-matrix/?filter=[). Use `[\S\s]` instead.

Comment: You can also use [`jsx.regexp.RegExp(/(.+?)[\.!\?(?="|')](\s|$)/, "gs")`](http://pointedears.de/scripts/test/regexp) to have it replaced automagically.

Comment: However, `[\.!\?(?="|')]` does not make much sense.  You cannot use assertions in character classes by escaping `?`, and it makes no sense to escape `.`; the former expression is equivalent to `[=|!.'"()?]`.

Comment: @PointedEars edited. I was just reusing the OP's expression because he said it worked for him.

Answer (score 2):

```
var arry = paragraph.split(/([.!?])\s/);
var sentences = [];
for (i=0; i < arry.length; i+=2) {
  // In case the last sentence is not delimited
  if (i < arry.length-1) {
    sentences.push(arry[i] + arry[i+1]);
  } else {
    sentences.push(arry[i]);
  }
}
```

Using a capturing group for the delimiter adds the delimiter to split's returned array.  Then you just need to fold it to put the delimiter back on the end.  This could be done a lot more cutely using a reduce or foldl method available in some frameworks, but I kept it to pure javascript for this example.

Comment: +1 for the capturing parentheses in split. I didn't know that, it addresses the issue with my initial answer.

Answer (score 1):

> So for example if I have a sentence like: `"Why is about.me so popular?"` I want it to say that that is one sentence and return an array like `['Why is about.me so popular?']`, but with this regex it splits it at the `"."` in `"about.me"`.

For a start, you can make the assumption that sentence-ending punctuation must be followed by whitespace or the end of input.  A sentence is then the *shortest possible* sequence of characters followed by either sentence-ending punctuation, followed by whitespace or the end of input.  “Shortest possible sequence” means that the matching must be *non-greedy* (`…+?`):

```
/*
 * ["The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. ",
 *  "Why is about.me so popular? ",
 *  "Give me a break!"]
 */
("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog."
  + " Why is about.me so popular?"
  + " Give me a break!").match(/[\S\s]+?[.!?](?:\s+|$)/g)
```

Your expression

> ```
> /[^\.!\?]+[\.!\?(?="|')]+(\s|$)/g
> ```

is mostly nonsense; it is equivalent to

```
/[^.!?]+[=|!.'"()?]+(\s|$)/g
```

You do not *need* to escape special characters in character classes (with the exception of `-` when between two other characters), and escaping them has no effect (with the exception of `\-` which then means a literal `-`).  Especially, you *cannot* use assertions like `(?=…)` in character classes; a character class *is* a (non-zero-width) assertion already.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of match, use split:

```
var sentences=paragraph.split(/\.\s/);
```

Comment: but the issue is that I don't want to loose the punctuation. When I split it will return the sentences without the punctuation.

Comment: ok, then maybe you should include this requirement in the question.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Grab everything that isn't a period then the period. 
([^.].)</strike>

http://rubular.com/r/pVxAPNCNxO

Edit:
(.*?(?:. ))

http://rubular.com/r/yv9kEPrKU2

Comment: The OP explained in the question why this doesn't work in his case.